# Regex to match a string based on particular character count

Tags: regex, python-3.x

It is not a duplicate question, other questions are about the repetition of a regex and my question is how can we get/limit a particular character count in regex for validation, I am looking for a regex to match a string only when the string has the count of character `'` as 1. 
Example:

```
patt = #IDontKnow
s = "Shubham's"
if re.match(patt, s):
    print ("The string has only ONE '")
else:
    print ("The String has either less or more than ONE ' count")
```

Comment: What have you tried? Please provide [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @MCVE, I am very new to regex and could not get any pattern yet.

Comment: Why won't you have a read first of [a manual](https://www.pythoncentral.io/introduction-to-python-regular-expressions/) and if you arrive at any issues then post your attempt?

Comment: @sophros, I have tried what I could do, but I am not getting any way in regex to get the character count and compare at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess what you are looking for is this:

```
import re
pat = "^[^\']*\'[^\']*$"
print (re.match(pat, "aeh'3q4'bl;5hkj5l;ebj3'"))
print (re.match(pat, "aeh3q4'bl;5hkj5l;ebj3'"))
print (re.match(pat, "aeh3q4bl;5hkj5l;ebj3'"))
print (re.match(pat, "'"))
print (re.match(pat, ""))
```

Which gives output:

```
None
None
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 21), match="aeh3q4bl;5hkj5l;ebj3'">
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 1), match="'">
None
```

What `"^[^\']*\'[^\']*$"` does?

`^` matches the beginning of string

`[^\']*` - `*` matches 0 or more characters from set defined in `[]`. Here, we have a set *negated* using `^`. The set is defined as one character - `'`, which is escaped so it looks `\'`. Altogether, this group matches any number of any characters **except** `'`

`\'` - matches one and only character `'`

`$` - matches end of the string. Without it partial matches would be possible which could contain more `'` characters. You can compare with above:

```
print (re.match("^[^\']*\'[^\']*", "aeh'3q4'bl;5hkj5l;ebj3'"))

<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 7), match="aeh'3q4">
```

Comment: Exaaaactly!! Thank you so much. But unfortunately, I have got many downvotes for it. :(

Comment: This is also useful in text editors to find missing closing quotes in text templates (pug, jade,...). Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use `.count()`?

```
s = "Shubham's"
if s.count("\'") == 1:
    print ("The string has only ONE '")
else:
    print ("The String has either less or more than ONE ' count")
```

Comment: Eggsactly what I was thinking. Python is much more than a wrapper for unnecessary complicated regexes.

Comment: @Mark, I need a regex, I have to give it as a validator in wtforms.